# Queryset contenttype show fields name and values in template table

Tags: python, django, content-type

I got a view that receives a model and field the user passes via post (existing model and field inside the app of course) and makes a queryset filter on it, then i need to show in my template that result in a table (name fields must be the column headers) and their respective values.

This what i got so far trying to serialize the queryset result in order to make it easier to show in template:

Views.py:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

class CommitteeReport(BaseView):

template_name = 'committee/committee_report.html'

def post(self, request, **kwargs):
    myfield = request.POST['field'].lower()
    my_model = request.POST['model'].lower()
    queryset_obj = ContentType.objects.get(model = my_model).model_class().objects.filter(**{myfield:True})

    return render(request, self.template_name,{
        'requirements': queryset_obj,
    })
```

And my template:

```
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_1">
            <table class="datatable table table-striped table-hover" cellspacing="0">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        {% for key in requirements %}
                            <th>{{ key.fields.name }}</th>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% for item in requirements %}
                        <tr>{{ item.fields.value }}</tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Thing is, i don't get result or if i change the tag inside the template, i get the objects dictionary for every row.

Any idea of how to achieve what i need ?, thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is or what output you want. Does your model have fields named `fields` or `value`?

Comment: What i need is to show in the template table the queryset field names as column headers and the queryset values normally. That field or value i put there is like foo, because i don't know how to show what i need based on the dinamic model the view receives. I've updated my question.

Comment: `objects.filter(**{myfield:True})` will only select the objects where the value of `myfield` is literally `True`. If you want to only display the values from a single db column / model field, you might want to check out the methods `values()` and `values_list()` of `QuerySet`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#values

Comment: @HåkenLid No, i know that, but what i need is not to show the value of one field but the entire queryset result in a table, including the field names as headers and all teh values the filter got.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the list of fields of model using `my_instance._meta.local_fields`. So you could try this in your view before `return`:

```
if queryset_obj.exists():
     fields = queryset_obj.first()._meta.local_fields
else:
     fields = []
return render(request, self.template_name,{
    'requirements': queryset_obj,
    'fields': fields,
})
```

And then using the context variable `fields` in your template:

```
<table class="datatable table table-striped table-hover" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    {% for field in fields %}
                        <th>{{ field.name }}</th>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for req in requirements %}
                    <tr>
                        {% for field in fields %}
                            <td>{{ req|lookup:field.name }}</td>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

where you define a custom `lookup` template filter to fetch the field value:

```
 def lookup(model, attr):
     if hasattr(model, attr):
         return getattr(model, attr)
     else:
         return None
```

Note: I'm assuming that all `requirements` are the same class and have the same structure, so that `requirements.0`, the first object in the QuerySet, is used for making the headers of the table.

Note 2: I haven't tried this, you might move some of the work to the view and pass easier variables as context variables (e.g. the list of field names).

Note 3: I haven't added error handling, you should check if `model` is actually a `Model` instance for example.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i'll check and let you know

Comment: Hi @dirkgroten , it doesn't work, shows  this error:  Variables and attributes may not begin with underscores: 'requirements.0._meta.local_fields'

Comment: Ok, I thought that might be the case (note 2), then you should create the `fields = requirements[0]._meta.local_fields` context variable in your view and loop through that in your template. Let me know if that works and I’ll update my answer.

Comment: Great, the headers work fine, but i got the same underline error when i use the req._meta.local_fields , and i don't know how to set it from the view, also the lookup tag should send value instead of name but show error too if i remove the ._meta iteration, any idea ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Updated my answer doing the `._meta` query in the view instead of the template.

Comment: Don't worry , i already did that but found another way to solve it. Thanks for all your help !!